# Find a set of vertices $U\subseteq V$ included in some simple cycle

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computer-science

> Let $G=(V,E)$, an un-directed graph. Find an efficient algorithm to return a $U\subseteq V$, where $u\in U$ is in some simple cycle of $G$.

So basically we've learned in class about the $low$ indicator, which defined as follows: $$low[v] = \min\begin{cases}
d[v]\\
d[u], (v,u) \text{ is a back-edge}\\
d[u], u \text{ is child of v in the DFS tree}
\end{cases}$$

Note: Here, $d[v]$ is the *time of discovering* the edge $v$ during the DFS scan.

I need to somehow utilize this indicator. More precisely, running [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) scan and updating this indicator for every vertex. Then, I need to come up with some rule to identify vertices which are part of some simple cycle.

Here below I've attached an example for every vxertex $v[x][y]$, $x$ identifies the *discovery time* and $y$ identifies the $low$ value of $v$.

I can't see a rule\ pattern and will be glad for an idea.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? And have you considered making something ANALOGOUS to the low-indicator, rather than assuming that this particular indicator is the one for you to use? I don't know whether such an approach might work, but I do know that trying to back-construct algorithms by guessing what was in the teacher's head when the problem was created is generally a bad idea (and doesn't give you a lot of expertise for handling real-world problems, where there's no teacher biasing the game).

Comment: You say "I have to run DFS..." but in your example, by the time you discover the edge CA, you should stop, because that forms a cycle. So running all of DFS would be a bad idea. That whole "I need to..." paragraph makes a bunch of assumptions that aren't really justified.

Comment: @JohnHughes, I need to find a set of vertices which are part of some cycle. Why should I stop then?

Comment: Because the vertices ABC form a cycle. So you're done. (Assuming that you can figure out that "b" needs to be included).